# iOS, facebook sdk. Like button for a group page concrete example?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-like, facebook-group

I want to write a function to allow to like a facebook group. My code is approximately the following:

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/likes", fbIdentifier];
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
if (!facebook.accessToken) {

    [self login:nil];
    return;
}
[facebook requestWithGraphPath:urlString andParams:dict andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];
```

and the result is:

```
Error Domain=facebookErrDomain Code=10000 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (facebookErrDomain error 10000.)" UserInfo=0x1dd77bc0 {error={
    code = 3;
    message = "(#3) Application does not have the capability to make this API call.";
    type = OAuthException;
}}
```

And my question IS NOT A DUPLICATE, because a lot of answers refer to an old version of facebook sdk or to examples with outer pages, objects and etc. but not inner pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't like a page from Graph API is forbidden, you can only like objects (url, images).

Comment: thanks. I fixed it and now it writes that it really doens't support like actions for pages